# Can I add a "Create New Folder" button in Files?

Tags: files, user-interface

When in Files, you can create a new folder by right-clicking on an empty space in the files window, then selecting New > Folder.

That is, except when there is no "empty space" in your window.

If there's already a long list of files and folders in your current window, the only option left for creating a folder is using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Is there a way I can place a "New Folder" button? I'm not the shortcut kind of guy.

Comment: Is this referring to when the window is in list view? Because otherwise I can't replicate this issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is not the solution you ask for, but I have an insiders' tip:

You can still use the contextmenu to create a new folder in a full list view.
Just right-click on the "select-checkmark-icon".

[image]

Comment: Oh, but you know what, I don't have the "select-checkmark-icon" because I disabled the "single-click" behavior. I use double click on items to activate them... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

When all the empty space is gone, just right click in the row at the top (where 'file name', 'size' etc. are) and the drop-down you need opens.